# Failed to map the library when using ISE to simulate a program connected with Modelsim

Tags: hardware, modelsim, simulate, xilinx-ise

> ERROR: Failed to map the library
> Reason: couldn't execute "vmap": no such file or directory`

I have tried to re-compile the Xilinx library, but failed. Could anyone spare time to give me some help?